# Matlab: Create workspace variables in unit testing

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, workspace

I have a class that read all variables from the workspace and get a list of all of them that are transfer functions (class type `tf`), and store them in another class (not represented here).

```
classdef TransferFunctionFactory < handle
  % This class allows to import a series of transfer function loaded from
  % different sources, like a file folder, workspace and so on..

  % Public section
  methods(Access = public)

    function collection = fromWorkspace(this)
      % Create a collection of transfer function that are stored in the workspace.
      % Returns:
      %  Collection of transfer functions.
      collection = App.TransferFunctionCollection();
      variables = who; % Here I should see w1, w2, w3, and w4 in variables
      for i = 1 : length(variables)
        if isa(eval(variables{i}), 'tf')
          trf = App.TransferFunction();
          trf.setAttribute('Name', variables{i});
          trf.setTransferFunction(eval(variables{i}));
          collection.addTransferFunction(trf);
        end
      end

    end
  end
```

I want to perform a unit testing, so I've created a test class:

```
classdef TransferFunctionFactory < matlab.unittest.TestCase

  methods (Test)

    function loadControllersFromWorkspace(testCase)
      collection = factory.fromWorkspace();
      testCase.verifyGreaterThanOrEqual(collection.getSize(), 3);
    end

  end

end
```

In order to perform unit testing, I need to set some variable in the workspace to be analysed from the function. I've tried something like:

```
function loadControllersFromWorkspace(testCase)
  factory = App.TransferFunctionFactory();
  assignin('base', 'w1', tf(1 + 's'));
  assignin('base', 'w2', tf(3 / 's'));
  assignin('base', 'w3', 4.3);
  assignin('base', 'w4', tf(1 / ('s' + 1)));
  who
  collection = factory.fromWorkspace();
  testCase.verifyGreaterThanOrEqual(collection.getSize(), 3);
end
```

but it does not work. when I enter the `factory.fromWorkspace` method, I cannot see `w1`, `w2`, `w3`, `w4` as output of `who`, and I cannot use them.

How can I set variables in workspace in the unit test class method, so they are visible from functions/methods that are called inside the test?

Comment: What is `'s'` meant to be in your final code block, and what are you trying to pass into `tf` during the `assignin` calls?

Comment: `s` Is something I need for defining a transfer function, it's not a variable

Comment: But do you realise that `1 + 's' = 116`? Because adding a value to a character will result in the character being treated as its character value...

Comment: this is how `tf` works: https://it.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html

Comment: Right, but nowhere in that documentation are you passing an integer value which is created by adding a character to a number. You specify `'s'` as an argument for continuous models, as a string. If what you're doing works for your purposes then okay, but I think you want `tf(3, [1 0])` instead of `tf(3 / 's')` which will be interpreted as `tf(3/115) = tf(0.0261)`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved, by using `evalin`. In my method I use it in order to read variables from base workspace when I need them:

```
function collection = fromWorkspace(this)
      collection = App.TransferFunctionCollection();
      variables = evalin('base', 'who');
      disp(variables);
      for i = 1 : length(variables)
        command = ['isa(', variables{i}, ', ''tf'')'];
        if evalin('base',command);
          trf = App.TransferFunction();
          trf.setTransferFunction(evalin('base', variables{i}));
          collection.addTransferFunction(trf);
        end
      end
    end
```

I've used it also in test method when I need to save variables in workspace:

```
function loadControllersFromWorkspace(testCase)
      factory = App.TransferFunctionFactory();
      evalin('base', 'w1 = tf(1 + ''s'')');
      evalin('base', 'w2 = tf(3 / ''s'')');
      evalin('base', 'w3 = 4.3');
      evalin('base', 'w4 = tf(1 / (''s'' + 1))');
      %who
      collection = factory.fromWorkspace();
      testCase.verifyGreaterThanOrEqual(collection.getSize(), 3);
end
```